# batch: how exit from for cycle without a label

Tags: batch

is here a command to exit from a FOR without using a "goto label"?

```
for %%c in (list) do (
 [some code]
 for %%i in (1 1 100) do (
   [some code]
   if [a condition] exit-this-for
   [some code]
   )
rem go here when exit
 [some code]
 )
```

i hate the labels!

Comment: I don't know what shell is this but most languages have the 'break' keyword to escape from loops

Comment: @TorbalanBG In batch (Windows/DOS) [`break`](http://www.computerhope.com/breakhlp.htm) is for turning on/off the ctrl+c sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you hate labels, refusing to use them limits your options here. I can't think of an easy way to do this within a single file. If you don't hate the idea of using two batch files, you can do something like this. Running `a.cmd` will `CALL b.cmd` and perform `ERRORLEVEL` check based on any `EXIT /B` in `b.cmd`.

a.cmd:

```
REM a.cmd  
@ECHO OFF
SET CHECKVAR=10

CALL b.cmd

IF ERRORLEVEL %CHECKVAR% (
    REM go here when exit from b.cmd met condition
    ECHO "B was %CHECKVAR%"
) ELSE (
    REM go here when exit from b.cmd did not meet condition
    ECHO "B was not %CHECKVAR%"
)
```

b.cmd

```
REM b.cmd
@ECHO OFF

FOR /L %%A IN (0,1,3) DO (
    ECHO "A: %%A"
    FOR /L %%B IN (0,1,100) DO (
        ECHO "B: %%B"
        REM Do what ever conditional check you like here.
        REM Just need to return some ERRORLEVEL to a.cmd.
        IF %%B==%CHECKVAR% (
            EXIT /B %CHECKVAR%
        )
    )
)
```